# how can i know when the NSXmlParser End Parsing for StopAnimating The UIActivityIndicatorView?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, uiactivityindicatorview

Hi all
how can i know when the NSXmlParser End Parsing for StopAnimating The UIActivityIndicatorView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-[NSXMLParser parse]` is a synchronous call. As soon as the parser returns from `-parse`, it has finished parsing.